# How to fix duplicate cscope ? is it a better way?

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

It is several years I am programming with vim and I used ctags.
I am working with a reasonably large C/C++ package and I need to find definition of functions. I usually use grep + ctags.
Recently I tried to use cscope instead of ctags and installed it with Vundle.
I see the following error for some of my files

```
E568: duplicate cscope database not added
```

I searched the web and found this:
[https://blogs.oracle.com/natarajan/entry/avoiding_duplicate_cscope_database_error](https://web.archive.org/web/20161012051523/https://blogs.oracle.com/natarajan/entry/avoiding_duplicate_cscope_database_error)
It doesn't work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your best bet on StackOverflow is to stick to one *question* per question, rather than adding a second question in a single post. As it is, your second question isn't a good format for StackOverflow anyway; StackOverflow works best with questions where there can be a "correct" answer, and asking for tool recommendations doesn't fit that format. See [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more info, particularly "Questions asking us to recommend or find...".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on [Artem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44116924/220155):

The Vim help for `cscopeverbose` is as follows:

> If `'cscopeverbose'` is not set (the default), messages will not be printed
>   indicating success or failure when adding a cscope database.  Ideally, you
>   should reset this option in your `.vimrc` before adding any cscope databases,
>   and after adding them, set it.  From then on, when you add more databases
>   within Vim, you will get a (hopefully) useful message should the database fail
>   to be added.

The problem here is that (a) there are multiple scripts attempting to load the `cscope.out` file and (b) they're not following the best practices of disabling the "verbose" cscope warnings before loading the file then re-enabling it afterwards, as suggested by the help text above.

The full error output should tell you which script is triggering this warning; for me it looked like this:

```
Error detected while processing /home/me_and/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim:
line   42:
E568: duplicate cscope database not added
```

The fix was then to edit the `~/.vim/plugin/cscope_maps.vim` file to add `set nocscopeverbose` immediately before the `cs add ...` lines. My version of this file already had `set cscopeverbose` immediately after, but if yours doesn't you should add that too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - this Q&A helped when I faced the OP's issue today. If you happen to know, I'm curious _why_ this patch is necessary. I encountered this problem for the first time after recently upgrading my fedora core from fc20 -> fc29. I had the same versions of vim and cscope installed before and after the upgrade, so I'm curious why things went from a working to nonworking state.

Answer (score 7):

Found the solution which worked for me (here: http://thoughtsolo.blogspot.com/2014/02/cscope-issue-duplicate-cscope-database.html):

Just add this line "set nocscopeverbose " to your ~/.vimrc file.

Answer (score 2):

As per the blog, "*This error pops up when VIM is already compiled with 'CSCOPE' module and you have also installed "cscopemenu.vim"*". I assume that you have a vim executable with has been `configure`d with `--enable-cscope` option.

Here's what I do:

- Download cscope source and build it, install the executable in a directory which is available in your `PATH`
- Download vim source code and `configure` it with `--enable-cscope`, build the source and install the executable
- Download [cscope_maps.vim](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim) and place it under `$HOME/.vim/plugin` directory. This contains cscope settings for vim.
- Create cscope database out of the source and header files. You may do something like the following

`find $PROJECT_HOME -name *.c -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" > cscope.files`

`cscope -qbR -i cscope.files`

You can add these commands in an alias and excute the alias every time you want to update your cscope database. These two commands create finally create `cscope.out` database file.

- Update .vimrc file to have the following

  `if has("cscope")
     set csprg=<location to cscope executable>
     set csto=0
     cs add <location to cscope.out>
  endif`

I hope after doing these steps you should be able to use cscope with vim easily.

Note that if you are working on multiple projects, you should be able to add appropriate environment variables to enable vim to pick the correct cscope database.

To answer your second question, may I suggest using [tagbar](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar). This will list your function names in the current source or header file. You can install it using `Vundle`. Add the following line to your `.vimrc`

`Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'`

Add this to your .vimrc to toggle tagbar view

`nmap <F4> :TagbarToggle<CR>`

Note that `F4` is just an example and you may use any binding to do the same.